# Disable secondary menu for a particular main menu item in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, menu, drupal-7, submenu

I have a website in Drupal, and let's say that we have a main menu and a secondary menu:

```
Main Menu Item 1
     Secondary Menu Item 1.1
     Secondary Menu Item 1.2
Main Menu Item 2
     Secondary Menu Item 2.1
     Secondary Menu Item 2.2
     Secondary Menu Item 2.3
     Secondary Menu Item 2.4
```

What I want to do is to disable the secondary menu just for the 2nd main menu. So, when the user is, for example, over the item 1, the items 1.1 and 1.2 appear, but when he is over the item 2, the items 2.1, 2.2, 2.3 and 2.4 do not appear. Is there any way that I can do that on Drupal?

Thanks, 
George

---

Edit 1: I use Drupal 7.19 and I don't use any module for menus, just the built-in ones.

---

Edit 2: Code

```
<div id="primary">
    <div id="primary-inner" class="clearfix">
        <h2 class="element-invisible">Main menu</h2>
        <ul class="links inline main-menu">
            <li class="menu-424 active-trail active"><a href="..." class="active-trail active">About Us</a></li>
            <li class="menu-549"><a href="...">News/Events</a></li>
            <li class="menu-411"><a href="...">Projects</a></li>
            <li class="menu-429 last"><a href="...">Getting Involved</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div> <!-- /#primary -->

<div id="secondary">
    <div id="secondary-inner">
        <h2 class="element-invisible">Secondary menu</h2>
        <ul class="links inline secondary-menu">
            <li class="menu-425 first"><a href="...">People</a></li>
            <li class="menu-484"><a href="...">Our Partners</a></li>
            <li class="menu-386 last"><a href="...">Our Groups</a></li>
        </ul>      
    </div>
</div> <!-- /#secondary-inner, /#secondary -->
```

Comment: Do you want to do this site-wide, or only on certain pages?, Oh, and please let us know which version of Drupal, and what, if any menu-related modules you're using.

Comment: Thanks Kyle for your reply. I use Drupal 7.19 and I use just the built-in modules for the menus. I want the secondary menu items of menu 2 to be disabled for the menu item 2 and all the sub-pages of any sub-menu that any of the secondary menu item can have.

Comment: Go to Menu management, edit the links and un-check 'expanded' box for that particular parent! They will still be available for breadcrumb! There is no point in using code or something!

Comment: Thank you very much Josh for your reply. I've already tried to do this, but they are still visible in the secondary menu. However, if I un-check the 'enabled' box they are not visible anymore! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not remove those items from the secondary menu then, at admin/structure/menu/<menu-name>

Comment: Because I want them on the breadcrumb. For example let's say that the item 2.1 is selected I want the breadcrumb to be
`Item 2 >> Item 2.1`

Comment: Ah, ok. You can use CSS to hide those specific menu items. Drupal does a good job of classing _everything_ (for better AND worse) so find the li.classname and set the display to none.

Comment: Thank Kyle. I used Javascript instead, though (completely noob with CSS - I tried but I didn't manage it).

Comment: It's kind of a shame to have to force remove the elements in such a manner. Here's a link to do so in [template.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7) As for CSS, that will more straightforward way of making this happen. Take for example, these two menu items from one of my sites: <li class="menu-5615 menu-path-blog even "><a href="/blog">Our Blog</a></li><li class="menu-2543 menu-path-faq odd "><a href="/faq">FAQs</a></li> In your theme's main css file, simply add "li.menu-2543, li.menu-5615 { display: none }" and elements visually removed.

Comment: Please look the 2nd edit on the original post. What I want to do is this: when the `menu-424` is selected the items `menu-425`, `menu-484` and `menu-386` should be invisible. Can I do that with CSS? Keep in mind that I don't always know what the sub-menus are. Thanks!

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you can hide the secondary, nested UL element if it is a child of li.menu-424. The CSS will look like this: li.menu-424 > ul { display: none; } hiding the UL and it's list-item children. This way, we don't 'care' what the list-items are, we've told the UL element to not display. Does that help?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29142/discussion-between-george-and-kyle-skrinak)